# Is it possible to plot markers based on which LayerControl is activated?

Tags: python, folium

I have setup two tile layers on my Folium map. Something like this:

```
folium_map = folium.Map(location=[50, 50], control_scale=True, zoom_start=2, max_bounds=True, prefer_canvas=False)
folium.TileLayer('openstreetmap').add_to(folium_map)
folium.TileLayer('google maps').add_to(folium_map)
```

I want to show a text only marker if Google Maps is selected and I want the marker to have text and an image if OpenStreet Maps is selected.

Is it possible to plot a unique set of markers to different tile layers?

==================================================

I have taken the dual-map suggestion and it works nicely. I am now trying to add subgroups to the feature group. However, it seems that dual maps does not like subgroups. The primary map (the one on the left) works. The secondary map (the one on the right) reverses the subgroup options and when selected, the popups appear on the primary screen. Is there a way to fix this? Here is my test code:

```
import folium
from folium import plugins
import pandas as pd

###############################################################################
# File paths
###############################################################################
main_dir = 'E:\Test\\'
output_dir = main_dir + 'Output\\'

###############################################################################
# Create test file
###############################################################################
# List1
Name = ['Tom', 'Mary', 'Juannita', 'Ivan', 'Peter', 'Lisa', 'Juan', 'Boris']
Lat = [ 51.507351, 38.90719,  19.432608,  55.755568, 51.47333, 38.890067,  19.521744,  55.650486]
Lng = [ -0.127758, -77.036871, -99.133208,  37.614361,  -0.134092, -76.984608, -99.219789,  37.732448]
Location = ['London', 'Washington', 'Mexico',  'Moscow', 'London', 'Washington', 'Mexico', 'Moscow']
Color = ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red']
Ownership = ['Partner', 'Partner', 'Own', 'Partner', 'Own', 'Own', 'Own', 'Partner']
Type = ['ABC', 'Acme', 'Acme', 'Acme', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'Acme', 'Acme']


  
# Get the list of tuples from two lists and merge them by using zip().
list_of_tuples = list(zip(Name, Lat, Lng, Location, Color, Ownership, Type))
   
# Converting lists of tuples into Pandas Dataframe.
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples,
                  columns = ['Name', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Location', 'Color', 'Ownership','Type'])

###############################################################################
# Folium Map Setup
###############################################################################
folium_map = folium.plugins.DualMap(location=[50, 50],
                                    control_scale=True,
                                    zoom_start=9,
                                    tiles=None,
                                    max_bounds=True, 
                                    prefer_canvas=False)

folium_map.fit_bounds([[180, 89], [-180, -89]])

folium.TileLayer('openstreetmap').add_to(folium_map.m1)

folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(
    tiles="http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}",
    attr="google",
    name="google maps",
    max_zoom=20,
    subdomains=["mt0", "mt1", "mt2", "mt3"],
    overlay=False,
    control=True,
    ).add_to(folium_map.m2)

minimap = plugins.MiniMap(toggle_display=True)
folium_map.add_child(minimap)

plugins.Fullscreen(
    position='topright',
    title='Expand me',
    title_cancel='Exit me',
    force_separate_button=True
    ).add_to(folium_map)

###############################################################################
# Layer Control:
##############################################################################@
mcg = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster(name="Locations with Images", control=False) # create marker clusters
folium_map.add_child(mcg)

###############################################################################
# ABC Stores
###############################################################################
fg1 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='ABC Stores')
folium_map.add_child(fg1)

g1 = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fg1, '\tOwn - ABC', show=False)
folium_map.add_child(g1)

g2 = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fg1, '\tPartnership - ABC', show=False)
folium_map.add_child(g2)

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['Type'] == 'ABC':
        kw = {"color": row['Color'], "icon": "shopping-cart"}
        icon_symbol = folium.Icon(**kw)
        popup = row['Name']
        if row['Ownership'] == 'Own':
            folium.Marker(
                location = [row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']],
                draggable = False,
                clustered_marker=True,
                tooltip = '<strong>' + str(row['Location'] + '</strong>'),
                popup = folium.Popup(popup, max_width=350),
                icon=icon_symbol
                ).add_to(g1)
        else:
            folium.Marker(
                location = [row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']],
                draggable = False,
                clustered_marker=True,
                tooltip = '<strong>' + str(row['Location'] + '</strong>'),
                popup = folium.Popup(popup, max_width=350),
                icon=icon_symbol
                ).add_to(g2)

###############################################################################
# Acme Fitness
###############################################################################
fg2 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Acme Fitness')
folium_map.add_child(fg2)

g1 = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fg2, '\tOwn - ACME', show=False)
folium_map.add_child(g1)

g2 = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fg2, '\tPartnership - ACME', show=False)
folium_map.add_child(g2)

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['Type'] == 'Acme':
        kw = {"prefix": "fa", "color": row['Color'], "icon": "camera"}
        icon_symbol = folium.Icon(**kw)
        popup = row['Name']
        if row['Ownership'] == 'Own':
            folium.Marker(
                location = [row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']],
                draggable = False,
                clustered_marker=True,
                tooltip = '<strong>' + str(row['Location'] + '</strong>'),
                popup = folium.Popup(popup, max_width=350),
                icon=icon_symbol
                ).add_to(g1)
        else:
            folium.Marker(
                location = [row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']],
                draggable = False,
                clustered_marker=True,
                tooltip = '<strong>' + str(row['Location'] + '</strong>'),
                popup = folium.Popup(popup, max_width=350),
                icon=icon_symbol
                ).add_to(g2)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(folium_map)

folium_map.save(output_dir + 'Test.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite a bit of time looking into this, but it seems that it is not possible to plot unique markers on different layers. It seems that the two maps side by side will do what I want. See [this page](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/plugin-DualMap.ipynb) for more information. See [this page](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/WMS_and_WMTS.ipynb) for how to make a tiled layer of Google Maps.

**Updated**
The code and images have been updated to reflect the fact that the questions have been edited and new issues have been added. The key to grouping markers using the subgroup function is to set up a parent-child relationship. In this case, since it is an example of multiple maps, the following parent-child relationship has been created to achieve this.

folium_map.m1 => fg_A(FueatureGroup) => g_1(SubGroup) => folium.Maker(g_1)

```
import folium
import folium.plugins

folium_map = folium.plugins.DualMap(location=[52.5, 5.15],
                                    control_scale=True,
                                    zoom_start=9,
                                    tiles=None,
                                    max_bounds=True, 
                                    prefer_canvas=False)

folium.TileLayer('openstreetmap').add_to(folium_map.m1)
folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(
    tiles="http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}",
    attr="google",
    name="google maps",
    max_zoom=20,
    subdomains=["mt0", "mt1", "mt2", "mt3"],
    overlay=False,
    control=True,
).add_to(folium_map.m2)

#fg_both = folium.FeatureGroup(name='markers_both').add_to(folium_map)
fg_A = folium.FeatureGroup(name='markers_1').add_to(folium_map.m1)
g1 = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fg_A, 'g1')
folium_map.m1.add_child(g1)

fg_B = folium.FeatureGroup(name='markers_2').add_to(folium_map.m2)
g2 = folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fg_B, 'g2')
folium_map.m2.add_child(g2)

#icon_red = folium.Icon(color='red')
#folium.Marker((52.6, 5.0), tooltip='both', icon=icon_red).add_to(fg_both)
g1.add_child(folium.Marker((52.4, 5.0), tooltip="1"))
g1.add_child(folium.Marker((52.0, 5.4), tooltip="2"))
g2.add_child(folium.Marker((52.4, 5.6), tooltip="3"))
g2.add_child(folium.Marker((52.0, 5.8), tooltip="4"))

folium.LayerControl().add_to(folium_map)

folium_map
```

[image]

Comment: I hope that my answers will help you get the answers you are looking for. If you find my answer useful, please click the check mark to accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the code. It does help but it seems that dual maps and FeatureGroupSubGroupd don't play well together. The left hand map works but the right hand map displays the subgroups in reverse order and when selected, the subgroups appear on the left had side map and not the right hand side.

Comment: The comment behavior is different from my environment, please check the [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DlmKJLABtKy2SPbTEzjtX4YBX6W1igQU?usp=sharing) code I extracted.

Comment: The code works nut when I took it to the next stahe and added subgroups, the markers do not work on both maps.

Comment: I do not know what group you added. Shouldn't you edit the question so that we can see what you added?

Comment: Using dual maps has answered this question . I am now expanding on the FeatureGroup by adding SubGroups.. SubGroups works on the left hand screen but the SubGroup on the right hand screen is reversed and when a subgroup is selected, it appears on the left hand screen. Here is my test code:

Comment: For example, if you want to add a new subgroup, you can do so by associating the new subgroup with the name of the higher-level group you want to associate it with.

Comment: Added my answers below you guys might want to check it out. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it's possible. Was having the same issue on the
first quarter of building our project but I made it worked
by doing this quite hacky codes.

First I loop the main markers then added it to my main map. I'm doing this inside a django app so I'm looping each marker object in my model. But you can apply your logic here instead.

```
#Main map markers
for marker in self.flood_markers:
    # There are codes here that allows the popup marker to contain 
    # images, but I removed it to keep the code short.

        popup = folium.Popup(html, max_width=200, max_height=300)

        barangay_markers = folium.Marker(
            location=[marker.latitude,marker.longitude],
            popup=popup,
            tooltip="Click For More",
            icon=folium.Icon(color="green",icon="glyphicon-flag")).add_to(landslide_map)
```

After that I created feature groups for different markers. Here I have 3 different markers.

```
    device_group = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Warning Systems & Evac Centers",overlay=False)
    evac_group = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(device_group,control=False)
    sign_group = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(device_group,control=False)

    list_devices = []
    list_centers = []
    list_signs = []
```

Then loop each markers to add it to its distinct lists. Creating these lists are important since this is our way to add each markers to its particular feature group.

```
# Other Markers
# Warning Devices (This will have a 'Siren' icon on its marker)
for device in self.warning_devices:

    # There are codes here that allows the popup marker to contain 
    # images, but I removed it to keep the code short.

    popup = folium.Popup(html, max_width=200, max_height=300)

    device_markers = folium.Marker(
            location=[device.latitude,device.longitude],
            popup=popup,
            icon=folium.Icon(color="red",icon="glyphicon-bullhorn"))

    list_devices.append(device_markers)

    for device in list_devices:
        device.add_to(device_group)
```

Repeat the process to other markers as well

```
# Evacuation Centers (This will have a 'House' icon on its marker)
for building in self.evac_centers:

    ...............

    list_centers.append(evac_markers)
            
    for building in list_centers:
        building.add_to(evac_group)

# Warning Signs (This will have an 'Exclamation' icon on its marker)
for sign in self.warning_signs:

    ...............

    list_signs.append(sign_markers)
            
    for sign in list_signs:
        sign.add_to(sign_group)
```

After appending each marker to our lists we then add these lists to our feature groups. Subsequently, add the feature groups to our map.

```
# add marker group to map
device_group.add_to(landslide_map)
evac_group.add_to(landslide_map)
sign_group.add_to(landslide_map)
```

Then finally, we need to set the main map layer as **"overlay=False"** and other layers to **"overlay=True"** and **control=False**.

```
# Map Layers
folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(tiles='Open Street Map',name='Main Layer',min_zoom=11,overlay=False).add_to(landslide_map) #This is the main layer   
folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(tiles='Stamen Terrain',name='Other Layers',min_zoom=11,overlay=True,control=False).add_to(landslide_map) #Setting overlay equals to False here makes the markers only show to a specific Layer.
 

    ....... More Map Layers .......
```

The result on the map main layer:
[image: Map main layer]

The second layer:
[image: map second layer]

Other layer:
[image: other map layer]

Hope this helps! I'm a newbie tho so I'm always open to any suggestions on how to improve my codes :)

Comment: And ohh! if you're wondering if you could add text only to a specific marker group popup,  YES! you can do that too. You just need to add a variable whenever you loop each marker and add what you desire to display on the popup. I removed it in my codes to make it shorter, but if you guys want it, I can edit my codes and add it there as well 